# What do the Scores Represent in Feature Selection and Cross Validation Pipeline in SciKit-Learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am running feature selection and cross-validation in a scikit pipeline to optimize hyperparameters within an SVR. We do mutual information feature selection first. As I understand it, the "pipeline" approach causes feature selection to be recomputed for every new fold of the CV. This prevents leakage of the training set into the test set.

However, we are not sure what `.get_support( )` returns in this context. If mutual info is recomputed for every fold of the dataset, the "K best" features will not be consistent across folds. Are the features returned by `.get_support( )` based on the scores over all folds for the best model? How is that score computed?

```
cached_pipe = Pipeline(
 [
 ('selector',SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression)),
 ('model',SVR())
 ],
 memory=memory
)

clf = GridSearchCV(
    estimator = cached_pipe,
    param_grid = hyperparameters,
    cv = passed_cv,
    scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error',
    return_train_score = 0,
    n_jobs= -1,
    verbose=0)

best_model = clf.fit(X, y.ravel())
HyperModel['feature_scores'] = best_model.best_estimator_.named_steps['selector'].scores_
HyperModel['feature_support'] = best_model.best_estimator_.named_steps['selector'].get_support()
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the source code for [get_support](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/feature_selection/_base.py#L26) and [scores_](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/feature_selection/_univariate_selection.py#L354)? Did you try running `SelectKBest` through `GridSearchCV` without pipeline and see what would be selected then?